# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'popleft'

Tags: python

I am trying to create a site-map generator. In a nutshell, I feed it a link, it looks for more links on the site and so on.

To avoid any long limbo-chains I thought I'd create a `blocked_sites.txt` which I can read from and compare my `unprocessed_urls` to and remove all the items that **CONTAIN** a blocker.

**My problem is that**, being naive I thought I could simply do some set/list comparing and removing, and viola, done, yet the problem was bigger mainly with the `collection *deque*`

**The code**

I start off by defining my strating url, which is the user input and I add it to a que:

```
 # a queue of urls to be crawled
unprocessed_urls = deque([starting_url])
```

Now comes the part where I'll start handling my urls:

```
    # process urls one by one from unprocessed_url queue until queue is empty
while len(unprocessed_urls):

    # Remove unwanted items
    unprocessed_urls = {url for url in unprocessed_urls if not any(blocker in url for blocker in blockers)} <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM

    # move next url from the queue to the set of processed urls
    newurl = unprocessed_urls.popleft()
    processed_urls.add(newurl)

    # extract base url to resolve relative links
    parts = urlsplit(newurl)
    base_url = "{0.scheme}://{0.netloc}".format(parts)
    if parts.scheme !='mailto' and parts.scheme !='#':
        path = newurl[:newurl.rfind('/')+1] if '/' in parts.path else newurl
    else:
        continue

    # get url's content
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Crawling URL %s" % newurl + Fore.WHITE) 
    try:       
        response = requests.get(newurl, timeout=3)
```

**So the problem** is, that the program shouldn't go onto big sites, that **I have explicitly defined to be blocked** like so:

```
# Blockers
blockers = set(line.strip() for line in open('blocked_sites.txt'))
```

And by using a suggested way of stripping the `unprocessed_urls` from the unwanted I use this bit of line(also pointed out in the code):

```
# Remove unwanted items
unprocessed_urls = {url for url in unprocessed_urls if not any(blocker in url for blocker in blockers)}
```

Thus we find ourselves here:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'popleft'
```

**What I could** devise from this is that by attempting to remove the *unwanted items* It's somehow altering the type of the `collection`

I don't really know how to move forward from here.

Answer (score 0):

The line `unprocessed_urls = {...}` creates a new `set` object and assigns it to `unprocessed_urls`. The fact that this new value is logically similar to the old value is irrelevant; assigning to a variable overwrites whatever was in there before.

However, a `collections.deque` can be created from any iterable, so you can instead do

```
unprocessed_urls = deque(url for url in unprocessed_urls if ...)
```

to create a new `collections.deque` so that all values you assign to `unprocessed_urls` will have the same type.